# Unexpected end of file when adding WFS on QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs

I'm getting messages "Unexpected end of file" when adding a WFS on QGIS. 
Should it be anything wrong with the URL or anything I could change?

Here is the URL which I tried to add and got the message.

http://sec.geodatenportal.sachsen-anhalt.de/wss/service/LVermGeo_INSPIRE_Raumbeobachtung_WFS/httpauth/licid-UUID_20140326-132415-051-81711-7868?Service=WFS&Request=GetCapabilities

Comment: Looks like this is a restricted service.  Do you also need to add user name and password somewhere?

Comment: I don't think so. It's supposed to be public and I haven't seen anything regarding to create an account or so.

Comment: It's using WSS, through I think con terra software and license manager.  INSPIRE doesn't imply open, so what reference do you have for it to be open?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong with the URL - I am not getting the Capabilities with the request. Just a "URL is not available" Message...

I tried another service from Sachsen Anhalt - this one is working:

https://www.geodatenportal.sachsen-anhalt.de/gateway/gateto/LVermGeo_Inspire-DVG_WFS_OpenData?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS&Version=1.1.1

Maybe its better to ask the Geoportal Sachsen-Anhalt for the correct URL.